# EF6 Transaction

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a scenario where i have a running total of user deposits.
I am trying to implement the concurrency mechanism that will ensure that two concurrent operation will not take place.

I could have used optimistic concurrency but it seem it wont do the job in my case.

In my case a new deposit transaction will depend on the previous one so i will have one read and one write in the database.

As understand i should have something like this done

```
     public DepositTransaction DepositAdd(int userId, decimal ammount)
    {
        using (var cx = this.Database.GetDbContext())
        {
            using (var trx = cx.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
            {
                try
                {
                    //here the last deposit ammount is read and new created with same context
                    var transaction = this.DepositTransaction(userId, ammount, SharedLib.BalanceTransactionType.Deposit, cx);
                    trx.Commit();
                    return transaction;
                }
                catch
                {
                    trx.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }                    
        }
    }
```

I spawn multiple threads that call the function but it seem they are not able to get the last data committed by previous call nor does function block and wait for the previous thread to complete.

Answer (score 0):

After getting deeper to documentation of SQL server i found that correct isolation level to achieve this is Serializable.